# Controlling Microsoft Teams Rooms via Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Are there any APIs available for controlling Microsoft Team Rooms (dedicated conference room hardware).

As a comparison of what I mean here is the Zoom Room API for controlling a Zoom Room (https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/guides/zoom-rooms/zoom-rooms-api).

I basically want to be able to get a team room to join a meeting. I see there is a call resource but I believe this is for start calls a bot rather than from a room.

Is this at all possible with Microsoft Team Rooms?

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/place?view=graph-rest-1.0) something you are looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately not, that would give me access to room information, but no way to start a Microsoft Teams Room video conference using the equipment in that room.

Comment: This is not available in Teams.